# Creating outline shapefile georeferencing existing map/pictures

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, georeferencing, administrative-boundaries

I need to create shapefiles (that need to be adapted and transfered for other programs) with the district outline of a couple of Caribbean countries.

Is georeferencing (using the *Georeferencing toolbar*) of pictures/maps online a good solution?

Is there any other method I can approach, possibly more professional?

What other measure should I take in order to make the shapefiles created can be used after (without basemap)? (Only thing off is Coordinate system, which in my case is WGS 1984).

Comment: Your question is not very clear, you want to know the best method for creating a GIS layer that shows the one to many islands (I'm not sure you are using the term georeferencing in the correct context?)?

Comment: I need to create a layer that shower further administrative areas within each island. Thought I can use already existing pictures of the districts and georeference them, but I don't think I can do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have the projected shapefile defining the various islands then you may use the georeferencing toolbar to georeference your images.  Once you have the images georeferenced you should create another shapefile (districts or something) from your island shapefile, and start an edit session and split/cut the various boundaries out referencing your georeferenced images.

Comment: That's what I was hoping to do. 
But how can I use the pictures to split up the existing big polygon (can't adjust transparency/display, so can't see through.
And what do you mean by creating a shapefile from the already existing shapefile?

Comment: Load your island layer into ArcMap, right click the layer in the table of centents, and select Export Data (and call it districts or something else).  As you stated you can adjust the image transparency as needed so you can see your district layer (or if this layer is a polygon than you can simply remove the fill and put this layer on-top of the image(s) layer).  This layer you may split/cut up it to represent the boundaries in your images.  There is no easy way to create the boundary lines automatically from the georeferenced images.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try and see if that works. So don't need georeferencing? Just visual referencing of the images?
Also, one last silly question - do I need to use a basemap all throughout this process, or is it enough if I just set up the Coordinate system?

Comment: Georeferencing attempts to put your images in the correct geo location.  Georeferencing should help aid in your splitting and cutting of your 'district' layer, so yes to your question.

Comment: Is there any way I can adjust the image/picture's transparency rather than the layer's transparency?

Comment: Yes, under Properties>Display tab.

Comment: Figured my mistake. Sorry for the silly questions. Kept on adding the pictures as a separate object rather than data though Add Data. Thanks so much for the help.

Answer (score -1):

Why can't you use a global data set?

http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=3864c63872d84aec91933618e3815dd2

or

http://www.gadm.org/

Comment: I thought of this already, but what I need to do is split Tobago for example or Barbados into smaller districts (Administrative areas), and don't know what I can use for that.

Comment: Try - http://www.diva-gis.org/gdata or try - http://www.gadm.org/country  Both of these have administrative district data you can download by specifying a country. Have not used them myself so let us know if this works for you.